# MVC 5 Custom Route - Error 404 in LegacyRoute : RouteBase (Example from the book Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 from Apress in chapter 16)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

The code provided in the book Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 from Apress in chapter 16 (Routing Incoming URLs) The example is about legacy urls. Next i will put the code samples for the custom route, routeconfig, controller and view.

**LegacyRoute.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace UrlsAndRoutes.Infrastructure
{
    public class LegacyRoute : RouteBase
    {
        private string[] urls;
        public LegacyRoute(params string[] targetUrls)
        {
            urls = targetUrls;
        }
        public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            RouteData result = null;
            string requestedURL = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath;
            if (urls.Contains(requestedURL, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                result = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                result.Values.Add("controller", "Legacy");
                result.Values.Add("action", "GetLegacyURL");
                result.Values.Add("legacyURL", requestedURL);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public  override  VirtualPathData  GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values) 
        {
            VirtualPathData result = null;
            if (values.ContainsKey("legacyURL") && urls.Contains((string)values["legacyURL"], StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                result = new VirtualPathData(this, new UrlHelper(requestContext).Content((string)values["legacyURL"]).Substring(1));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**RouteConfig.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Mvc.Routing.Constraints;

using UrlsAndRoutes.Infrastructure;

namespace UrlsAndRoutes
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

            //routes.MapRoute("NewRoute", "App/Do{action}", new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional });

            //routes.Add(new Route("SayHello", new CustomRouteHandler()));

            routes.Add(new LegacyRoute("~/articles/Windows_3.1_Overview.html", "~/old/.NET_1.0_Class_Library"));

            routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            routes.MapRoute("MyOtherRoute", "App/{action}", new { controller = "Home" });
        }
    }
}
```

**LegacyController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace UrlsAndRoutes.Controllers
{
    public class LegacyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetLegacyURL(string legacyURL)
        {
            return View((object)legacyURL);
        }
    }
}
```

**GetLegacyURL.cshtml**

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetLegacyURL";
    Layout = null;
}
<h2>GetLegacyURL</h2>
The URL requested was: @Model
```

I can't figure how to put it work. I always get 404 error (http://my.machine/articles/Windows_3.1_Overview.html). The method in the GetRouteData in LegacyRoute.cs is never called. If I remove the . from the URL the code works fine. Can anyone give some advice or help?

It is strange that no one are complaining that the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Page 445 provides the solution. You need to edit IIS Express settings.

Right click on the IIS Express icon on the taskbar while the application is running -> Show all applications -> Click on the site you want to configure -> Click on the configuration file

Search for `System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule`

Remove the preCondition attribute value so the line becomes `<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />`

Restart the application and you are ready.

Answer (score 0):

routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

```
        routes.Add(new LegacyRoute("~/articles/Windows_3.1_Overview.html/",
                                   "~/old/.NET_1.0_Class_Library/"));

        routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}", new { controller = "Home" ,action="index" });
         routes.MapRoute("MyOtherRoute", "App/{action}", new { controller = "Home" });
```

Try with above code , this should be worked.

Malinda Sanjaka